# Return current android layout or screen width for debugging

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to add come conditional processing depending on screen width. I set up a `refs` in my `/res/values` to point to the appropriate resource on screen width > 600 (`sw600dp`), have the two layouts, etc. Then I have

```
Log.d(TAG, "From mButton onClick, layout: " + getActivity().????);
if (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dialog_widget) == null) {
    Intent intent = WidgetActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), mThinger.getInfo());
    Log.d(TAG, "From mButton onClick, intent: " + intent.toString());
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INFO);
} else {
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    WidgetDialogFragment dialog = WidgetDialogFragment.newInstance(mThinger.getInfo());
    dialog.setTargetFragment(ThingerFragment.this, REQUEST_INFO);
    dialog.show(manager, DIALOG_INFO);
}
```

I never hit the `else` condition, so I am trying to add a `Log` (see first line of code block) to let me know what layout elements are available, or what the screen width is, or anything to help me know why I'm not seeing the fragment on larger screens.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help a bit - at startup of my app I always log:

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    Log.e(TAG,"dpHeight= "+dpHeight+" dpWidth="+dpWidth);
```

And one other trick to log the screen layout determined by the system is to use the "values" layout-specific folders:

```
values-sw320dp/
values-sw420dp/
values-sw600dp/
values-sw720dp/
```

and in each folder define a strings.xml (or any value resource) which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="selected_configuration">sw320dp</string>
</resources>
```

and in App main `Applicaton` class log:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Selected configuration: "+getString(R.string.selected_configuration));
```

You can use another resource value besides string of course.

Comment: Thanks, I used your method to solve my problem! I should have probably thought of that, but I'm new enough that I'm still clunking through a bit :-/